# Restore Files From After a Commit on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have worked on my files for few days without committing.

Today I worked with the GitHub client, don't know what I exactly did but all my files were restored to an old commit.

And than, without understanding that my files have just changed to the old commit, I committed my files - thinking I am committing most updated files.

All of my work from the last few days disappeared.

How can I restore my work?

Comment: haven't you committed on GitHub, or you haven't committed at all (neither in your local repository)?

Comment: at all. 1. did some work 2. accidentally restored to old commit 3. committed again. any solution? doesn't it saves the files in any way before restoring?

Answer (score 4):

The big lesson here is:

## Commit early, commit often.

If you restored an earlier state (I'm not sure how the GH client does this, but probably through `git reset`) without committing, your work is gone.

Comment: this is no answer. if github restore my files without saving a copy of the current version and without prompting me - it means that github sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Git is much different from other VCS.
You should commit as often as possible: that is every time you reach a point you're somewhat satisfied.
Git gives you the chance to review, change, squash your commits and much more before sharing your changes with others.

But if you haven't committed, the only chance you have is to look to some filesystem tool to recover deleted files.

Comment: same thing -  if github restore my files without saving a copy of the current version and without prompting me - it means that github sucks.

Comment: github uses git, and if you want to restore a previous commit (when haven't yet committed) it thinks you're unsatisfied with your changes and want to trash them.
Unfortunately if you haven't committed at all, your work is lost.
You could have some chance to recover it from the history of your IDE.

Comment: "Somewhat satisfied" doesn't even cover it. "Do something that works" is more like it. Finish a method on a class? Commit. Successfully change the style of a single element? Commit. Create boilerplate code? Commit. Small, incremental (but still working) commits.

Answer (score 0):

IF you've committed your work locally, even if you created some problem in push-pull with a remote repository, you should be able to recover something from the [reflog](http://kparal.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/git-tip-of-the-day-recover-lost-commits/) command.

Comment: haven't. 1. did some work 2. accidentally restored to old commit 3. committed again. any solution? doesn't it saves the files in any way before restoring?

Comment: If you did't commited your work is not possible in git. You can search for some other tool like system restore previous version Feature in Windows